# FreeSWITCH Conference advertise

Tags: freeswitch, conference

I can't understood completely how work presence on FreeSWITCH Conference. The default code in **conference.xonf.xml** is:

```
<advertise>
  <room name="3001@$${domain}" status="FreeSWITCH"/>
</advertise>
```

Any hint?

Thank you
Regards